# Why is the Jupyter kernel dead during the second iteration of object tracking using YOLOv8 and DeepSORT?

Tags: python, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, yolo

I am going to detect and track the objects in a video file using YOLOv8 and DeepSORT respectively by importing their packages. In the first iteration of the frame reading, everything is normal but, in the second iteration, Jupyter notebook kernel is dead at `tracks = tracker.update_tracks(results, frame=frame)` line. What can be the reason?
Code is the following:

```
import torch
import cv2
import ultralytics
from deep_sort_realtime.deepsort_tracker import DeepSort

model = ultralytics.YOLO("yolov8m.pt")
tracker = DeepSort(max_age=50)

CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD = 0.8

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if not ret:
        break
        
    detections = model(frame)[0]
    
    results = []
    for data in detection.boxes.data.tolist():
        
        confidence = data[4]

        if float(confidence) < CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD:
            continue
        xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = int(data[0]), int(data[1]), int(data[2]), int(data[3])
        class_id = int(data[5])
        results.append([[xmin, ymin, xmax - xmin, ymax - ymin], confidence, class_id])
        
    tracks =tracker.update_tracks(results, frame=frame)
    for track in tracks:
        if not track.is_confirmed():
            continue

        bbox = track.to_tlbr()
        track_id = track.track_id
        class_name = track.get_class()        
        
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I have found out that the problem is caused by `covariance = (
            np.linalg.multi_dot((self._motion_mat, covariance, self._motion_mat.T))
            + motion_cov` line in the _kalman_filter.py_ file in the _deep_sort_ folder. Type of the arguments is `numpy.ndarray()`. More, all the arguments are 8x8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was upgrading the `numpy` and `scipy` to the latest version since, I was using the latest version of Jupyter Notebook.